# Dom element update without clearing the innerHtml using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I have the following shopping list in my HTML.

```
<html>
   <body>
     <ul>
      <li> Milk items 2 </li>
      <li> Veg item 4 </li>
      <li> Eggs 5 crates </li>
     </ul>
     <button id="double">double</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

Now I want to double each item quantity, one way is to clear innerHtml of ul and put again the appropriate data. Is there any other way to do so? If yes, please describe. If not then is this method is efficient what if we have millions of list items ( for educational purposes only).
Thanks,

Comment: You can iterate through all <li> items and run a function on them that changes the innerText. Your function has to be pretty solid though as there can be a lot of cases in your problem.

Comment: "*Is there any other way to do so?*" - yes, there is. There are many possible solutions, each of which will have caveats of some sort. "*[Please] describe*" - no, you find the solution - and undertake the research to best satisfy your requirements - and then try to implement a solution that you prefer. If you have problems with that solution - or even with the current solution - then ask your questions about those specific examples. As it stands this question is far too broad to be answered in the SO format, since whole books could be written about the potential solutions and problems.

Comment: I do understand the question, but you are expected to ask a specific programming problem, with clearly stated expectations and problems. Then we can offer help that’s useful. This open ended question is not a fit for this site, because there’s no objectively correct answer and because the vast range of solutions could, as noted, fill books. Please: take the [tour], read the “*[ask]*” guidance, and learn what the site is for, and what our expectations are.

Answer (score 0):

You can add *quantity* `attribute` to the items and wrap the numbers in the `li` in `span`. Then multiply the `attribute (quantity)` by *2* and update each `li` > `span` *HTML*.

```js
// Get the button and the list
var btn = document.getElementById('double');
var list = document.querySelector('.list');

// Add event (click) to the button
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Get the items in the list 
    var li = list.querySelectorAll('li');
  
    for(var i = 0; i < li.length; i++){
        // Get the quantity attribute of each item 
        var quantity = parseInt(li[i].getAttribute('quantity'));
        // Get the span of each item and update the HTML = quantity multiplied by two
        li[i].querySelector('span').innerHTML = quantity * 2;
    }
});
```

```html
<ul class="list">
    <li quantity="2"> Milk items <span>2</span> </li>
    <li quantity="4"> Veg item <span>4</span> </li>
    <li quantity="5"> Eggs <span>5</span> crates </li>
</ul>

<button id="double">Double</button>
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, thank you

Comment: No problem at all, voting if the answer was helpful will be appreciated :)